# SQL Converting Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I want to perform the following conversion:

```
Seniority    Price   Rating
---------------------------
   1          P1      R1
   2          P2      R2
   3          P3      R3
```

to

```
Value RowId ColId
------------------
 1     0      0
 P1    0      1
 R1    0      2
 2     1      0 
 P2    1      1
 R2    1      2
 3     2      0 
 P3    2      1
 R3    2      2
```

If possible I would like to preserve the field name as well in the transformed table, i.e. all rows with rowid=0 will have Seniority added as a field, rowid=1 will have Price, so on.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option using JSON if 2016+   An XML version is available for older version.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Seniority] varchar(50),[Price] varchar(50),[Rating] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'P1','R1')
,(2,'P2','R2')
,(3,'P3','R3')


Select B.Value
      ,A.RowID
      ,B.ColID
 From  (Select *
              ,RowID = row_number() over (order by (select null))  - 1
         From  @YourTable    --<<< Replace with virtually any table.
       ) A
 Cross Apply (
                Select *
                      ,ColID = row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1
                 From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ) ) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('RowID')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**EDIT - Just for Fun, the XML version**

```
Select C.Value
      ,A.RowID
      ,C.ColID
 From  (Select *
              ,RowID = row_number() over (order by (select null))  - 1
         From  @YourTable 
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML RAW)) ) ) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select ColID = row_number() over( order by (select null)) - 1
                      ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                 From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                 Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') not in ('RowID')
             ) C
```

**EDIT -- XML Version to ALLOW NULL values**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Seniority] varchar(50),[Price] varchar(50),[Rating] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'P1','R1')
,(2,'P2','R2')
,(3,NULL,'R3')   -- Forced a NULL value


Select C.Value
      ,A.RowID
      ,C.ColID
 From  (Select *
              ,RowID = row_number() over (order by (select null))  - 1
         From  @YourTable 
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL)) ) ) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                      ,ColID = row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1
                 From  XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(nd)
                 Cross Apply C1.nd.nodes('./*') as C2(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('RowID')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
Value   RowID   ColID
1       0       0
P1      0       1
R1      0       2
0       0       3
2       1       0
P2      1       1
R2      1       2
1       1       3
3       2       0
        2       1  --<< Notice NULLs return as Empty Strings
R3      2       2
2       2       3
```

Comment: I want to include NULLs as well, if you know it off the top of your head.  Otherwise, I'll implement it myself.

Comment: @MarkC NULLS are excluded from the JSON version.  However, in the XML version there is a tweak that will pass a NULL as an empty string (not a null)

Comment: I am using the XML version.  That tweak would work just fine.

Comment: @MarkC Forgot the Where Item not in ('RowID')  --- updated

Comment: @MarkC It dawned on me that I didn't update the JSON option to include NULL.  I added  ... ,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES

Comment: @MarkC If you have 2016+, the JSON approach is more performant.

Comment: I am not on 2016+.  Thank you for the extensive help.

Answer (score 1):

As a general approach, `union all` works:

```
select seniority, 'seniority' as which, seniority - 1, 0
from t
union all
select p1, 'p1' as which, seniority - 1, 1
from t
union all
select r1, 'r1' as which, seniority - 1, 2
from t;
```

Comment: I wanted to see if someone had a good dynamic solution with UNPIVOT.  I need to transform pretty much any table given into that format.  I'm not sure if this is a great way as I'd have to generate this all with dynamic sql.